# Debugging a logic error in a Denary to binary converter (C++ 17)

Tags: c++, binary, calculator, cmath

So I have been working on a Denary to Binary convertor in C++ and I keep getting an error with the output statement.

```
cin >> entered_number;
bit_size = log(entered_number) / log(2);    
conversion_fill = exp2(bit_size);

if (conversion_fill != 1){
    while (conversion_fill != 1){
        conversion_numbers.push_back(conversion_fill);
        conversion_fill = conversion_fill/2;            
    }
    conversion_numbers.push_back(1);    
}

for(auto a : conversion_numbers){
    if (entered_number >= a){
        entered_number = entered_number - a;
        output= output + "1";
    }
    else{
        output= output + "0";
    }
        
        
cout << output;
```

This is the code I had written. Conversion_numbers is the vector which stores the numbers used to convert denary number to binary and conversion fill is the variable to store the largest conversion number. I chose the output to be a string so that it could concatenate either a 1 or a 0 to the final string depending on what is required.

For example, if i entered in 56, i should expect an output of 111000. Instead I get an output of 111111111011100111000. Where have i gone wrong?

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger, and what did you find?

Comment: please provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) this code not compiling

Comment: For me this code works fine and outputs 111000. You probably forgot to reset one of the variable. You should try to add output.clear() and conversion_numbers.clear() before everything else. The output you got also ends on 111000 so it's probably output.